# wp.media issue with selected image

Tags: theme-development, uploads, media, media-library

First of all, I know there are many questions related to this question. But what the problem is that they are all related somehow to jquery.

But my question implements the vanilla javascript.

Basically, everything works fine except the onselect(). I am unable to get the URL of the attachment.

**Here is the code.**

```
var custom_uploader;

var uploadButton = document.getElementById('upload_logo_button');

uploadButton.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if ( custom_uploader ) {
        custom_uploader.open();
        return;
    }

    custom_uploader  = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
        frame: 'select',
        title: 'Choose Image',
        button: {
            text: 'Select Image'
        },
        multiple: false
    });

    custom_uploader.onselect = function() {
        var attachment = custom_uploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
        console.log(attachment);
        var uploadLogoImage = document.getElementById("upload_image").innerHTML(attachment.url);
    }

    //Open the uploader dialog
       custom_uploader.open();
});
```

Will please someone tell me why I am unable to get the URL of the image even the image gets successfully uploaded to the WP media.
Thanks in advance. If anyone needs further info, please don't hesitate to ask. Once again thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`custom_uploader` is actually an instance of [`wp.media()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Javascript_Reference/wp.media) and not an HTML element, so the variable does *not* have a `onselect` property, but it does have a `on()` method/function which you can use to listen to the `select` event which is triggered after an attachment is selected.

Secondly, an HTML element does *not* have a `innerHTML()` *method*, only a property of the same name that we can use to change the inner HTML of the element like so: `<Element>.innerHTML = 'foo <b>bar bold</b> baz'`. Please check the [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) for more details.

So to fix the issues, change this:

```js
custom_uploader.onselect = function() {
    var attachment = custom_uploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
    console.log(attachment);
    var uploadLogoImage = document.getElementById("upload_image").innerHTML(attachment.url);
}
```

to:

```js
custom_uploader.on( 'select', function() {
    var attachment = custom_uploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
    console.log(attachment);
    var uploadLogoImage = document.getElementById("upload_image").innerHTML = attachment.url;
} );
```

Also, if `#upload_image` is actually an `<input />` or textarea field, then use the `value` property to change the input/textarea value, or you could instead use [`setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute).

Comment: Thanks, its working now.